# Can I draw on top of a canvas inside of another canvas?

Tags: python, drawing, tkinter

I am creating a Solitaire clone using Python's Tkinter window toolkit. My window contains a main canvas, and within the main canvas a series of widgets that inherit from Canvas that hold the cards. I have implemented a "Drag to Move" system where a user can click the mouse down to select a card in one of the inner canvases, drag it to a new canvas, and let go to place the card into the receiving canvas.

**The Problem:** I want to draw the cards in motion between the canvas on which they are drawn, and the canvas they are moving to, so the user can see them moving across the screen during the click and drag motion. When I try to draw cards in-between the canvases that I already have, they are always drawn behind, meaning I can only see cards through the padding around the inner canvases.

Here is an example where I drew several of them so the effect could be seen clearly, and the inner canvases are also clearly visible.

[image: a screenshot of the overlap problem]

**What I've Tried:** I've tried to move the canvases back using Misc.lower(aCanvas), but i wasn't able to create the desired effect. I've also tried to design a custom overridden cursor, but it seems my cursor size is limited to 32px*32px, which is insufficient for the size of the card images I want to move.

**My Question:** How can I draw on top of a canvas that is inside of another canvas? If I can't, how would you solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do what you want. Embedded widgets are always above the canvas items.

Why is it that you are embedding canvases insidebcanvases? Why not just use a single canvas?

Comment: The canvases inside of my canvas are actually specialized collections that inherit from Canvas with methods like addCard(), removeCard(), dragNDropStart(), etc. I didn't want to handle drawing on foundation, tableau, draw, and waste piles all from a single canvas object. This was my attempt a being object oriented in python.